# Treating string as a list object in python

Tags: python

I'm writing a python program that takes user input from the command line. The user is told to enter in values in a list format, i.e. the user might enter `[1, 2], [2, 7], [4, 3]`, etc.

I'm splitting this input string at `", "`  so that my program has access to a list such as:

```
['[1, 2]', '[2, 7]', '[4, 3]']
```

Is there any way to convert each of these "string lists" into actual lists? I don't want to have to split these strings and remove the brackets, extract the values, and create a new list manually.

Thanks!

Comment: No, the split function will split the commas inside the brackets too

Comment: You have to use some string operations, there's no 'automatic' way.

Comment: Does `eval()` work? Aside from all the security vulnerabilities and bugs and ... Never mind.

Comment: You could surround the input in `[]`, then it would become a valid JSON list and you could use `json.loads` to parse it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are asking the user for a literal Python list, you can ask Python to eval the list for you. `literal_eval()` only works with literals, so it's not possible to slip malicious actions into the input as you could with `eval()`

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval('[1, 2], [2, 7], [4, 3]')
([1, 2], [2, 7], [4, 3])                           #input was a tuple

>>> list(literal_eval('[1, 2], [2, 7], [4, 3]'))
[[1, 2], [2, 7], [4, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import json
data = json.loads("[%s]" % user_input)
```

`user_input` is the str your user have input. in your case it is

> [1, 2], [2, 7], [4, 3]

`data` is what you want - a list contain two item lists.

Comment: hm, I'm getting "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded."

Comment: @Danny give me the user input str

Comment: This would be correct if the querent was asking for json literals to be evaluated.

Comment: I'm passing the user input as the *args to a function. When I print out this input within the function I get: (['[1, 2]', '[2, 7]', '[4, 3]'],)

Comment: @Danny So that another thing, your user_input string is not like the one you described in your question.Maybe your method of get the user input have some error.

Comment: @Danny, why are you passing it as `*args`? Is this homework or something?

Comment: No, not homework. I'm passing the input to a function that is supposed to create a text file and write blocks of text of dimensions specified by the user to the file.

Comment: @Danny you can do this by using `json.loads("[%s]" % ",".join(args))`.But this is really ugly.I dont understand why you use `*args`.Btw, John La Rooy's function is a better one to me.So I suggest you use `list(literal_eval(",".join(args)))`, do not forget the import clause

Comment: So I want the user to be able to provide an arbitrary number of lists and then I want the program to draw blocks based on those lists.